# Executing javascript function when all async-handlers completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous

As example, in SIGINT handler I need to wait until all child processes are completed. But there may be handlers on child`s 'close' event, which themselves may execute async actions like external notifications.

So I need to wait until

1. child.closed and
2. child.closed handlers completed and
3. async actions initiated in child.closed handlers are all completed.

Below goes simplified current code that is aware only of second checkpoint.

```js
var child_process = require('child_process');
var events = require('events');
var timers = require('timers');

var childRunning = false;   // has child flag (counter in actual app)

// starting child
var child = child_process.spawn(process.cwd()+'/stub.js',{detached:true});
childRunning = true;
child.on('close',function(){childRunning=false});   //

// example close handler with async action inside
// actually there is a bunch of such handlers
child.on('close',function(){
    console.log('child close handler triggered');
    timers.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('close handler async action completed')
    }, 2000);
});

process.on('SIGINT',function(){
    console.log("Received SIGINT");
    closeApp=function(){
        console.log("readyToExit");
        process.exit();
    }
    if (!childRunning) closeApp();
    // in fact, i need here not this event, but 
    //   'all close handlers are done their job'
    child.once('close',closeApp);
})
// actually there is a daemon app, so it does not stop by itself at all
```

In this example normally you will see "close handler async action completed" message, but if you press ctrl+c then that message will be missed. So I need somehow to rewrite it to se

I'm trying to find a solution which keeps close-handlers as simple as it can be.
I don't know how to name this case, so googling didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use some extended EventEmitter which

1. can handle promises, returned by event listeners
2. implement `Q.all()`-like behavior for collected promises
3. emit another event on all-listeners-completed (including wait for promises)

I will try to find such in npm registry or will implement one myself if nothing found.